# Saving moment format in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, momentjs

I am trying to save a date in Mongoose using moment.js. My schema looks like this:

```
const personSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  joined: { type: Date, default: () => moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') }
})
```

However, when I access the document in the database the time format is 2020-02-08T21:08:02.000+00:00, not 2020-02-08 21:08:02 as it should be...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2020-02-08T21:08:02.000+00:00 format is called ISODate. Instead of saving it with Moment in Mongoose (it seems MongoDB stored it in ISO format anyhow), I saved the date as the regular

```
Default: Date.now
```

then, when presenting the date in my view, I used

```
moment(myObject.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

And the date was presented as intended.

Answer (score 0):

type: String << Change to string.